# How do I use FetchedResultsController if I have two different kinds of cells?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a prototype tableview in IB, which has two different kinds of cells: a complete cell, and a basic cell (for displaying articles, I use each one depending what kind of article it is).

I want to integrate FetchedResultsController into my app so I can use CoreData to populate the tableview, but previously (using an NSArray instead of FetchedResultsController) I handled the cell setup as follows:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    int row = indexPath.row;
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = nil;
    Article *article = self.articles[row];

    // Checks if user simply added a body of text (not from a source or URL)
    if (article.isUserAddedText) {
        CellIdentifier = @"BasicArticleCell";
    }
    else {
        CellIdentifier = @"FullArticleCell";
    }

    ArticleCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // If the user simply added a body of text, only articlePreview and progress has to be set
    cell.articlePreview.text = article.preview;
    cell.articleProgress.text = [self calculateTimeLeft:article];

    // If it's from a URL or a source, set title and URL
    if (!article.isUserAddedText) {
        cell.articleTitle.text = article.title;
        cell.articleURL.text = article.URL;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

But now I don't know how to check whether or not it is a basic article or not (as before I checked that property of the Article object in the NSArray). One article I saw did this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell =
        [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Set up the cell...
    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}
```

But I need to know what kind of article it is before I even decide what the cell identifier is, so I don't see how I could do it here. Am I able to get the FetchedResultController object early, query it to see what the value of the article property is (whether or not it's basic) and set the CellIdentifier accordingly? Or is there something else I should be doing?

TL;DR: How do I decide the CellIdentifier depending on the kind of object to be shown in the cell when using FetchedResultsController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your exact same logic as you was doing before just the retrieval of the `Article` looks a little different

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  Article *article = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

  NSString *CellIdentifier = [article isUserAddedText] ? @"BasicArticleCell" : @"FullArticleCell";

  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

  // Set up the cell...
  [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

  return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you retrieve the object from the fetchedResultsController, you can check the type and then decide what type of cell to create based on what it returned.  For example:

```
id result = [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
if ([result isKindOfClass:[MyObject class]]) {
   // It's a MyObject, so create and configure an appropriate cell
} else ...
```

Comment: Depending on how you're getting your article objects, you could also set/define an "isBasic" BOOL flag that you could look for before setting up the cell.

Comment: As an attribute in the entity, you mean?